# Back up iPad to Mac automatically

Tags: macos, ipad, backup

I stopped using iCloud backup on my iPad because of excessive data usage*. I now back my iPad up to my Mac instead. However, as far as I can see, this has to be done manually - I have to remember to navigate to the iPad in Finder and click "back up now", otherwise it doesn't happen.

So my question is, is there a way to schedule backups of my iPad to my Mac, so that they happen automatically? Ideally I'd like to have it back up every day, and keep at least the last few days of backups, so that I can restore to an earlier time if I need to.

<sub>*this is because an app I use, [Blankbook](https://www.legolas.me/blankbook-english), stores all its data in a single file, which is hundreds of Mb in size and updates every day. This file is the main thing I want to keep backed up.</sub>

Comment: What version of macOS? My Mac automatically backs up my iPhone over WiFi (Big Sur & iOS 14.6). You do have to check the appropriate options in Finder to show the phone in WiFi, etc. Also I got iMazing a while back and that does backups automatically over WiFi as well.

Comment: @SteveChambers this is on Catalina. For some reason I never thought to check "show this iPad when on WiFi" - I've checked it now and will see if that makes it perform backups automatically.